# Install new APK version over Play Store version using App Signing

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore, android-app-signing

I'm using App Signing for my new app (I only have the upload key right now). But I was wondering how I could install a new APK over the Play Store version. Right now when using the upload key it doesn't install because the certificates do not match. I tried to create a new keystore and changed the certificate with the one you can download on the console (App signing certificate). But this also doesn't work. I always do one last test to make sure everything is working accordingly. Just to clarify. I don't want to upload APK to the beta channel. I want to directly install the APK from the filesystem which should be installed over the Play Store version.

How can this be done?

**Edit**

I don't know why I got downvoted. So I'll explain how App signing works. When enabling app signing on the Play Store, the real signing certificate is in control by the Play Store. The only certificate/keystore you sign with is an upload keystore. So if you sign your app with an upload keystore it does not have the same certification as when the Play Store signs it. This is why I tried to download the app signing certificate from the Play Store to get a matching certification, but this didn't work.

Comment: Please be more precise. What does "Not working" mean? Even when you sign your app with the same key you get "Certificates do not match"? If you do not have access to the original certificate information you can not install over the signed app.

Comment: @HendrikMarx I have provided some extra information. I'm using app signing in the Play Store. Which means that the real signing certificate is in control of the Play Store (so not by me). I only have an upload keystore. I want to sign the APK in the same way the Play Store does, so I can install the APK over the Play Store version. But since I only have the upload keystore I don't know how this is done

Comment: I am getting INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when running adb install myapp.apk because, according to SO, the app is already installed (duh) – is this the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this easily. There are two recommended alternative options right now:

1. Have a development device (phone) which doesn't have the Play store version installed, and use that for installing from the FileSystem.
2. Use your alpha channel for development, and upload it to the Play store and have the Play store deliver the update over the Alpha channel.

But right now there is no way of getting Play to sign an APK which isn't published to the store.

Comment: I was worried this was going to be the answer. Very unfortunate. If by any chance you do come across a way to do this, please let me know. But for now I'll accept your answer